# Read Only on Whole Drive

Tags: 16.04, boot, server, mount, read-only

is there anyway to fix my ubuntu server 16.04 LTS from read only error?

Before that, I tried to update grub and update initramfs for disabling swap, then after reboot, it happens... it quite sucks anyway.

The Thigs that I've tried is fsck -f on my /dev/sda1 it only show noncontagious file 0.1% and the rest is normal and boot on recovery mode for it. if I do mount and remount it works, but I want it works even after I do reboot. Thanks, help apprciate, I quite desperate because If I do the clean install, my lemp stack will gone with everything...

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the output of `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: I've Fix it, I Accidentaly comment out the main HDD. Too Bad.. It's solved now